# getting A/libc(15282): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) error when running robotium

Tags: android, fatal-error, robotium

I am testing my android project using robotium. Project is built on 4.3 version. When I test it manually there is no issues. But when I run the robotium testcases it is throwing below mentioned error and crashed.

```
  10-25 12:40:28.807: A/libc(15282): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000008a (code=1), thread 15282 (android.safeway)
```

If this is an issue of project then it shoud crash when i test it manually right? I dont know why i am getting this error only when running robotium. As per my understanding this issues coming when network fetching is happening. please help me. i am stuck with it.

Comment: I see the same error sometimes when a native method (ndk) crashes. Usually, the crash occurs (at least for me), when calling native methods from a background thread. Perhaps robotium is doing it's stuff in a background thread as well. Are you using the ndk inside your project?